# ImageMosaic colors always GREY

Tags: geoserver

I followed this tutorial downloading all the resources
https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/imagemosaic_timeseries/imagemosaic_timeseries.html

I was able to reproduce everything, but I have an issue with colors.
Everything I put inside ImageMosaic become GREY.

So instead of visualizing https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/_images/step_3.png 
with blue colors

[image]

I see everything GREY.

[image]

Comment: did you set a style for the layer?

Comment: Ok I added the style and selected it inside the layer. Getting closer, but I see a very different one https://www.dropbox.com/s/r11z2ygl6bqm2nf/preview-1.png?dl=0 - everything is blue.

Comment: are you manually adding a TIME parameter to your preview URL?

Comment: yes. time=2009-10-01 following the tutorial